# Why does Linux Torvalds not sign his Git commits?

Tags: digital-signature, pgp, gnupg, git

Why does Linux Torvalds not sign his Git commits (with GPG)?
Recent example: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/566cf877a1fcb6d6dc0126b076aad062054c2637

Pretty scary. How can I be sure that he really does the commits? https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10005577

Comment: how is it scary if someone else came up with "Fearless Coyote" instead of him?

Comment: Because it could be backdoored?

Comment: We can only speculate as to why someone else does something.

Comment: Torvalds wrote git and has expressed his opinions in detail in this and other forums: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/GPG-signing-for-git-commit-td2582986.html